# Given an array S of size N , check if it's possible to split sequence into two sequence

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array `S` of size `N`, check if it is possible to split sequence into two sequences - `s1 to si` and `si + 1 to sN` such that first sequence is strictly decreasing and second is strictly increasing.
Input Format
First line contains a single integer `N` denoting the size of the input.
Next `N` lines contain a single integer each denoting the elements of the array `S`.

Constraints
`0 < N < 1000`, Each number in sequence `S` is `> 0` and `< 1000000000`

Output Format
Print boolean output - `"true"` or `"false"` defining whether the sequence is increasing - decreasing or not.

Sample Input
5 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5

Sample Output
true

Explanation
Carefully read the conditions to judge which all sequences may be valid. Don't use arrays or lists.
My code scored `77.78/100` scores, I am unable to figure out the error, can anyone please help me out.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    long long int p,c;

    cin >> n;
    cin >> p;
    bool dec=true;
    int a=0;
    if (n<=0 || n==1) {
        a=1;
    }
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> c;
        if (p==c) {
            a=1;
        }
        else if (p<c) {
            if (dec) {
                dec=false;
            }
            else {
                dec=false;
                a=0;
            }
        }
        else if (c > p) {
            if (dec) {
                a=0;
            }
            else {
                a=1;
                dec=false;
            }
        }

    }
    if(a==0){
        cout<<"true";
    }
    else {
        cout<<"false";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you set a to 1 you should break out of the loop otherwise it may get changed back to 0 again

Comment: did still 2 of the test cases failed

Comment: a sequence `2 2 3` can be split into `2` and `2 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code on some test cases and it seems that your code fails on,

```
n = 2
1 1
```

It's answer should be True as it can be broken into {1}, {1} and since single element is increasing as well as decreasing both, the answer is true.

Here is my code
Explanation: My whole concept is based on we need to check if given sequence could exactly be broken in 2 sub-sequences. So i kept a variable Seq_no to keep track, so if in the end of the code if Seq_no value should not exceed 2, also since there is possibility that a sequence could be entirely strictly decreasing so in that case if n is not equal 1 then answer is true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{

    int n, curr, prev = INT_MAX, Seq_no = 1;

    int i;

    cin >> n;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> curr;

        if(Seq_no == 1) // for stricly decreasing
        {
            if(prev <= curr)
            {
                Seq_no++;
            }

        }
        else  // for stricly decreasing
        {
            if(prev >= curr)
            {
                Seq_no++;
                break;
            }

        }
        prev = curr;
    }

    if(Seq_no == 2 || (Seq_no == 1 && n != 1)) 
        cout << "true\n";
    else 
        cout << "false\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If i solved your problem then pls. accept the answer.